# Create a file with newlines in bash

Tags: bash

In bash, I have a string containing `\n` characters. When I `echo -e $mystring` it formats as I expect in the console, respecting the newline characters. However, when I redirect the output to a file, the resulting file is all one line, minus the `\n` characters, even if I use the `-e` flag:

`echo -e $mystring > myfile.txt`

However, tabs `\t` are respected. How can I get the formatting right in the file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Double quotes (`"`) should help.

```
$> mystring="\na\tb\nok"
$> echo -e "$mystring" > ./file
$> cat ./file 

a   b
ok
```

You should use `\r\n` instead of `\n` for "Windows newlines".

Comment: It shows up ok in `cat`, but when you open with a text editor it is all one line...

Comment: It's something with your text editor. Seems work fine in `vim`, actually.

Comment: So how do I get a format that will respect newlines on a Windows machine and a Linux machine?

Comment: Is the text editor notepad?  If so, it needs CR LF, not just CR

Comment: "Newlines on a Windows machine" is a "\r\n".